# Blazor how to add/remove class on only one element with same class not all of them

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor, onclick, blazor

I'm new to blazor I have 2 (or more) elements with same class `booksMain` I want to make them disappear on click. How I could add class on click or css but I want to add only on the one clicked not all `booksMain`-s

Is it possible without JS Interop

[image]

and

[image]

Another example

[image: Just 5 buttons with same class and color]

```html
<button class="btn btn-success" @onclick="ChangeColor">Click Me1</button>
<button class="btn btn-success" @onclick="ChangeColor">Click Me1</button>
<button class="btn btn-success" @onclick="ChangeColor">Click Me1</button>
<button class="btn btn-success" @onclick="ChangeColor">Click Me1</button>
<button class="btn btn-success" @onclick="ChangeColor">Click Me1</button>
```

How to make this work?

Comment: Don't put images of your code, please add the text of the code so others can copy it more easily.

Comment: It's just an example it's not a "Not working code" I just mean a lot of elements with same class but I want to add class to one of them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@page "/"

@foreach (var item in items)
{
    <button class="@item.Color" @onclick="@(() =>  item.Shown = !item.Shown )">@item.ID</button>
}

@code {
    List<Book> items = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(i => new Book { ID = i, Title=$"Title{i.ToString()}", Shown = false }).ToList();

    public class Book
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public bool Shown { get; set; }
        public string Color => Shown ? "green" : string.Empty;
    }
}
```

### app.css or style.css

```
.green {
background-color: green;
```

}

Note: The above code is a simple toggling... now model your code accordingly.

Update as per request... Note that the above solution is much better than the following one:

```
    @page "/"

<button type="button" class="@Color[0] btn btn-success" @onclick="@(() => ChangeColor(0))">Click Me1</button>
<button type="button" class="@Color[1] btn btn-success" @onclick="@(() => ChangeColor(1))">Click Me1</button>
<button type="button" class="@Color[2] btn btn-success" @onclick="@(() => ChangeColor(2))">Click Me1</button>
<button type="button" class="@Color[3] btn btn-success" @onclick="@(() => ChangeColor(3))">Click Me1</button>
<button type="button" class="@Color[4] btn btn-success" @onclick="@(() => ChangeColor(4))">Click Me1</button>

@code {
    string []Color = new String[] {"", "", "", "", "" };



    private void ChangeColor(int index)
    {
        if (Color[index] == "")
        {
            Color[index] = "blue";
        }
        else
        {
            Color[index] = "";
        }
    }
  }
```

### app.css or style.css

```
.blue {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: No I mean I have 3 div-s each has class booksMain I want to onclick add a class "disappear" to the element that I clicked

Comment: Would you mind marking it as the answer if it solved your problem, so others know it was useful.

Comment: Thanks a lot for such detailed code,I upvoted it :) but I'm still trying to read and understand it 

Comment: Could you please tell me on the buttons because I got really confused in that code, just 5 simple buttons each has a class btn I want to change their color by clicking like in the picture if I clicked on the 5th the 5th would become blue